# Laravel 5.7 Form Request не проходит валидация

Tags: laravel

Проблема такая, создал FormRequest для валидации вводимых данных выглядит так:

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

use Auth;

class ProfileValidationRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        if(Auth::check())
        {
            return true;
        }

    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|max:255|alpha_dash',
    ];
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
        'name.required' => 'Поле ввода не должно быть пустым или иметь пробелы',
        'name.max' => 'Логин не может содержать больше 255 символов',
        'name.alpha_num' => 'Поле можно содержать только алфавитные символы, цифры, знаки подчёркивания "_" и дефисы "-"',
    ];
}
}
```

При вводе любых данных даже правильных валидацию не проходит и всегда выдаёт первую ошибку:

> Поле ввода не должно быть пустым или иметь пробелы

При этом метод, естественно не выполняется.Уже всё обыскал никак не пойму в чём ошибка.

Метод в контроллере выглядит следующим образом:

```
public function setusername(ProfileValidationRequest $request)
    {
            $username = $request->login;

            Auth::user()->name = $username;
            Auth::user()->save();
            return redirect('/profile');
}
```

Вот что в форме:

```
@if ($errors->any())
       <div class="alert alert-danger inline-block">
            <ul>
                 @foreach ($errors->get('name') as $message)
                               <li>{{ $message }}</li>
                 @endforeach
            </ul>
       </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Покажите форму, откуда отправляется запрос на сервер

Comment: И еще вопрос: почему в Request у вас `name`, а в контроллере уже `$request->login`?

Comment: @Alexxosipov Да, я очень невнимателен, большое спасибо.